Is it possible to reuse <ng-container> in the same html code?
I have a child component that I need to show a part of its html code for multiple times in the same html file (in child.html). The code is inside a <ng-container></ng-container> (I can't replace it with <ng-template></ng-template>).
Is it possible to reuse it in the same .html file several times?
Here is my code:
Parent.ts:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    standalone: true
})
export class ParentComponent {
    @Input() form!: FormGroup;
    @Input() id!: string;
}

Parent.html
<app-hello-world
    [id]="id"
></app-hello-world>


Child component:
.ts:
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'app-hello-world',
    templateUrl: './hello-world.component.html',
    standalone: true
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {
    @Input() form!: FormGroup;
    @Input() id!: string;
    @ViewChild('helloWorld') helloWorldView!: ElementRef;
}

.html
<div #helloWorld [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- first show--> 
    <ng-container #hello>
        <p>Hello world </p>
    </ng-container>

   <!-- second show--> 
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hello">
   </ng-container>
</div>

I'm trying ngTemplateOutlet but I'm getting:
error TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'TemplateRef<any>'. <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hello">

ng-container cannot be reused, please explain why you cannot use ng-template? also the full scenario

@NarenMurali Because this component is a child of another component, and when I use  the parent doesn't render the child!

please revise the question with respect to ng-template, so that it can be replicated on stackblitz, require minimal reproducible code

why don't you make it separate component and call any times you need it.

@NarenMurali I've updated the code  to see the parent and child components!
